# How do I write string value as MongoDB ObjectId in java spark?

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, objectid

I'd like to write string value as ObjectId to MongoDB in java spark.

I tried it like this.

```
List<StructField> structFields = new ArrayList<>();
structFields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("oid", DataTypes.StringType, true));

StructType structType = DataTypes.createStructType(structFields);

spark.sqlContext().udf().register("toObjectId", (String publisherId) -> {
    return new com.mongodb.spark.sql.fieldTypes.api.java.ObjectId(publisherId);
}, StructType);

dataframe = dataframe.withColumn("pub_id",
    functions.callUDF("toObjectId", dataset.col("publisherId").cast(DataTypes.StringType))
);

Map<String, String> writeOverrides = new HashMap<String, String>();
writeOverrides.put("writeConcern.w", "majority");
WriteConfig writeConfig = WriteConfig.create(jsc).withOptions(writeOverrides);

MongoSpark.save(dataset, writeConfig);
```

but I got this error.

```
Caused by: scala.MatchError: com.mongodb.spark.sql.fieldTypes.api.java.ObjectId@8b2d2973 (of class com.mongodb.spark.sql.fieldTypes.api.java.ObjectId)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:379)
```

How can I write ObjectId to MongoDB in spark through JAVA API ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `udf()`
import the `struct` first:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct;
```

Then use:

```
dataframe = dataframe.withColumn("pub_id", struct(col("publisherId").as("oid")))
```